# Doesnt work/recognize language in faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf-2, localization, faces-config

The language "TR" is not worked/ does not recognized. Here is my code for **faces-config.xml**.

```
<locale-config>
      <default-locale>tr</default-locale>
      <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
<resource-bundle>
      <base-name>resource.index</base-name>
      <var>msgs</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

- My properties file located in source/resource named as index_tr.properties. the other languages such as china,canada,etc. it works.
- I found these language in Locale java class and recognized it doesnt include Turkish. How can I solve this Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my property file as below.

index.properties -> index_en.properties

Does it necessary to do this? I have read that without any suffix after the word, it is

default as English language, isn't it?